# Ruby Metaprogramming "Depths"

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm starting to learn metaprogramming in Ruby and (I think) I'm understanding how to add instance methods and variables, but only if passed in one at a time. For example, `test.new_value = true`. I'm wondering how to add an extra depth to my command with two dots `test.like.this`. For example:

```
class StackOverflow
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def method_missing(argument, *args)
    argument = argument.to_s

    if argument =~ /failing/
      puts 'FOUND FAILING'
      puts argument
      puts args[0]
      return
    end

    if argument =~ /this_test_is/
      puts 'FOUND THIS TEST IS'
      puts argument
      puts args[0]
      return
    end

    if argument =~ /this_works=/
      instance_variable_set("@#{argument.to_s.chop}", args[0])
      return
    else
      return instance_variable_get("@#{argument}").to_s
    end
  end
end

test = StackOverflow.new("post")
test.this_works = true
puts "IT WORKED: " + test.this_works
test.this_test_is.failing
```

gives me the following output:

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

IT WORKED: true
FOUND THIS TEST IS
this_test_is

undefined method `failing' for nil:NilClass
(repl):44:in `<main>'
```

What I'm looking to do is treat this as a variable and value pair. I'd like to know how to do both of these scenarios:

A: Recognise `this_test_is` and treat it as a variable to have it store the string (or symbol is fine) `failing`.

B: Recognise `failing` as the variable and if I see `this_test_is` then set `failing` to `true`, as opposed to `false` if I find `this_test_is_not`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If we define "metaprogramming" as "code that writes code", then there's none of that here, yet. And, judging from your verbiage, this task _might_ be too advanced. Before one attempts something like this, he better have a clear understanding of core ruby/oop concepts: variable vs. method vs. message, return values and how to return objects from methods, various ways of storing state of an object and when to use which, and so on, and so forth.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The motivation for this question came from https://www.codewars.com/kata/5571d9fc11526780a000011a which leads me to believe it's not too advanced for Ruby.

Comment: For ruby - no. For you today - likely yes :) That problem is 3 kyu, one of the higher difficulties.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev which I agree with you on. I'm just pointing out it's a task suited for Ruby, going against your original statement before you edited it.

Comment: Well yes, people do this kind of thing in ruby all the time. I never said otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to this kata, it looks very interesting. So many possibilities. I should do it sometime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some kind of recursion :

```
class StackOverflow
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def method_missing(argument, *args)
    argument = argument.to_s

    if argument =~ /failing/
      puts 'FOUND FAILING'
      puts argument
      puts args[0]
      return
    end

    if argument =~ /this_test_is/
      puts 'FOUND THIS TEST IS'
      puts argument
      puts args[0]
      return StackOverflow.new("this_test_is")
    end

    if argument =~ /this_works=/
      instance_variable_set("@#{argument.to_s.chop}", args[0])
      return
    else
      return instance_variable_get("@#{argument}").to_s
    end
  end
end

test = StackOverflow.new("post")
test.this_works = true
puts "IT WORKED: " + test.this_works
test.this_test_is.failing
```

prints this :

```
IT WORKED: true
FOUND THIS TEST IS
this_test_is

FOUND FAILING
failing
```